# Purpose of Rails lib/assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, assets

Pretty much everywhere quotes the Rails Guides

> lib/assets is for your own libraries' code that doesn't really fit
>   into the scope of the application or those libraries which are shared
>   across applications.

Thats great, but what does it mean?

If it is my library, I would either use a gem or bower (which will install in vendor).
Why would I manually put things in lib/assets that are shared across applications and have them included in the repo? Sound like a mess..

Would love a concrete example of things that should go into lib and not vendor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the code is internal, written by you, your team or your company, and it is shared between projects (or is a clearly discrete library within your project) but not added to a gem or a bower package because it is not publicly distributed, you might want to add it to lib/assets.

You may also choose to put a stable, discrete file or folder of assets, like a piece of JS functionality, that is only for this app, into lib/assets, to indicate it is more stable than other code.

Comment: how will the code be shared if its in a folder within the app?

Comment: It's just a text file, or a folder. The same way you might share those things normally.